# How add WSDL web reference to.NET Standard library

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, wsdl, visual-studio-2019

I need to consume this WSDL:
`https://testapi2.schenker.pl/services/TransportOrders?wsdl`

But I have a problem with adding reference to .NET Standard library.

For .NET Framework library I had options to add web reference like on below screens.

- [Service reference menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G92fU.png)
- [Add service reference menu - window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Am0eX.png)
- [Add service reference - advanced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvwpB.png)
- [Add service reference - advanced - compatibility - web reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/10ezW.png)

But for .NET Standard or .NET Framework I have completely different options for that.

- [Connected Services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Si6Ij.png)
- [WCF Web Service Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KcIo.png)

Also I get warnings:

```
Cannot import wsdl:port
Detail: There was an error importing a wsdl:binding that the wsdl:port is dependent on.
XPath to wsdl:binding: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://api.schenker.pl/TransportOrders/']/wsdl:binding[@name='TransportOrdersBinding']
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://api.schenker.pl/TransportOrders/']/wsdl:service[@name='TransportOrdersService']/wsdl:port[@name='TransportOrdersPort']
Cannot import wsdl:binding
Detail: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
XPath to Error Source: //wsdl:definitions[@targetNamespace='http://api.schenker.pl/TransportOrders/']/wsdl:binding[@name='TransportOrdersBinding']
```

Is there any possibility that I can add that WSDL to .NET Standard as Web Reference?
Or it's a problem of that Schenker service that is only compatible with old .NET Framework?

Why it's a problem, because I need to host target application od linux machine.

WSDL file:
`https://pastebin.com/p0nrLiwe`

TransportOrderds.xsd
`https://pastebin.com/w6Edzdjz`

StandardTypes.xsd
`https://pastebin.com/0pu6YJuA`

Comment: I tried that wsdl with a .Net stack and that doesn't work either because it needs authentication. I suggest you download the WSDL as file as well as all imported schema's and then generated from file instead from the url directly.

Comment: I've try it without result, still the same error. Here is a WSDL file https://pastebin.com/ynT2ApAD

Comment: but you need to download https://testapi2.schenker.pl/services/TransportOrders?xsd=TransportOrders.xs as well  and  https://testapi2.schenker.pl/services/TransportOrders?xsd=StandardTypes.xsd  and if those xsd's have schemaLocations then you need to download those as well. Then you have to edit the wsdl and the xsds to point to the files on disk instead of that webserver.

Comment: I fixed WSD file and added XML schemas (changed path to local), but still get the same error. You can look on main topic, I added there hyperlinks.

Answer (score 0):

> You can try two options here except Connected Services.

Options 1 - Try to consume the WSDL with similar to the service model metadata, using dotnet-svcutil. This is a command-line tool to generate web service references for .NET Core and .NET Standard. 
[Reference for dotnet-svcutil](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/additional-tools/dotnet-svcutil-guide?tabs=dotnetsvcutil2x)

Option 2 - Use the channel factory to consume WCF service. The drawback of this option is you should know about the contract definition of the WCF service you would like to consume. I created a small WCF service and tried it out, it was less trouble making method.

I defined the known WCF contract in the ASP.NET Core MVC project, as shown below,

```
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace AspNet_Core_Wcf_Client.Contracts
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IOrderService
    {
        [OperationContract]
        int GetOrdersCount();
    }
}
```

This contract defined in my WCF as well.

Then consumed the this service from the controller as shown below.

```
using AspNet_Core_Wcf_Client.Contracts;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace AspNet_Core_Wcf_Client.Controllers
{
    public class OrderController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            // create binding object
            BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();

            // create endpoint object
            EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost:64307/OrderService.svc");

            // create channel object with contract
            ChannelFactory<IOrderService> channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IOrderService>(binding, endpoint);

            // Create a channel
            IOrderService client = channelFactory.CreateChannel();
            int result = client.GetOrdersCount();

            ViewBag.Count = result;

            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

To use successfully channel factory method needs to install ServiceModel from nugget packages.